# Methods to show linear independence of functions, polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

There are apparently many methods to show that a set of functions are linearly independent.

Forexample, there were some cases, where I saw use of derivative. At least to prove Lgrange polynomials are lin. indep., they were evaluated at certain points and their coordinates formed identity matrix which showed that they are linearly independent.

I guess, the later shows that polynomials are linearly independent iff the set evaluated at a number of points are linearly independent.

Are there other methods to show linear independence of functions/polynomials?

Comment: If your space has an inner product, you can show functions are pairwise orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if applying a linear map to the vectors (functions) produces (clearly) linearly dependent images, then the original vectors must have been linearly dependent. The linear map is often to a space $K^n$ or (in case of infinite sets of vectors) to the space $K^\mathbf N$ of infinite sequences of scalars, because linear independence can often easily be established in such spaces (for instance in the case of vectors that is already in echelon form). Giving a linear map to these spaces just means giving a (finite or infinite) sequence of *linear forms*, linear functions that take scalar values. Evaluating a function, or one of its derivatives, in a point is one type of example of a linear form (and taking a certain coefficient of a Taylor series is basically the same thing); computing a definite integral is another.

This will explain many of the examples you encountered. Of course one needs to carefully choose the sequence of linear forms to get the desired result for a given set of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Here some methods can be used:

- A family of polynomials $(P_n)$ graduated in degree  is linearly independant;
- A family of polynomials $(P_n)$ graduated in valuation  is linearly independant;
- Using the Taylor expansion we can show that a set of functions is linearly independant, for example $(\cos x, \sin x, \tan x^2)$
- We can show that the family $(\cos nx)_{n\geq 0}$ is linearly independant by calculating
  $$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(nx)\cos(mx)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

I know Gram determinant and [Wronskian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wronskian.html) determinant.
Gram determinant can be used to determine linear independence of functions belong to $L^2$ space.